# How to implement useContext (React Native, Expo) to control weather unit settings?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-context

I am trying to implement the ability to switch between imperial and metric units using the useContext() hook. So far, I have not had much success. I have read the React useContext() [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) and followed [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-reacts-context-api-and-usecontext-hooks-effectively-ed98ad9343b6). This is my current JavaScript source code that currently does not function as intended:

**App.js** - where context provider is located

```
import React from 'react';

import WeatherScreen from './components/screens/WeatherScreen';

import { CurrentUnitContext } from './components/hooks/CurrentUnitContext.js';

export default App = () => { 
    
    return ( 

        <CurrentUnitContext.Provider
            value={"imperial"}
        >
            <WeatherScreen />
        </CurrentUnitContext.Provider>

    );

};
```

**CurrentUnitContext.js** - Intended for createContext()

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

/**
 * WIP custom hook for setting current unit
 * 
 * todo - change weather units here
 * set imperial (F), metric (C), and maybe standard (K)
 */

export default CurrentUnitContext = createContext();
/**
export default CurrentUnitContext = createContext({

  theCurrentUnit: "imperial",
  setTheCurrentUnit: () => {},
  
});
*/
```

**UnitSwitch.js** - Intended to contain the component to set the units with user feedback.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

import { CurrentUnitContext } from '../../hooks/CurrentUnitContext.js';

import { tailwind, fontConfig } from '../../../tailwind.js';

/**
 * Unit Switcher child component. Based on switch's boolean
 * value useState hook isEnabled, set useEffect hook currentUnit
 * to either "imperial" or "metric".
 * 
 * @param - switchHeader: Displays the unit switch header
 * text passed from WeatherContent.js
 * @param - imperialUnits: Text passed from WeatherContext.js for
 * imperial unit button string.
 * @param - metricUnits: Text passed from WeatherContext.js for
 * metric unit button string.
 */

export default UnitSwitch = ({ imperialUnits, metricUnits, switchHeader }) => {

    const [theCurrentUnitSetting, setTheCurrentUnitSetting] = useState("imperial");

    return (

        <View style={tailwind('bg-gray-300 border-t-2 p-3 w-64 h-48')}>

            <Text style={tailwind('text-center text-22fz')}>
                {switchHeader}
            </Text>

            <View style={tailwind('flex-1 justify-center items-center')}>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={tailwind('')}
                    onPress={() => setTheCurrentUnitSetting("metric")}
                >
                    <Text style={tailwind('')}>
                        {metricUnits}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

        </View>
    );
};
```

**getWeather.js** - Hook designed to fetch weather

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

import useLocation from '../hooks/useLocation.js';
import { CurrentUnitContext } from './CurrentUnitContext.js';

/**
 * @getWeather - if permission was granted in useLocation() hook,
 * uses Object theLocation containing lat. and long. coordinates as
 * decimal number values. Returns the currentWeather. useEffect()
 * relies on the value of Object theLocation.
 *
 * @WEATHER_API_KEY - accessed from clientSecret directory,
 * hidden for repo security and must be manually provided.
 * @currentWeather - useState hook to store JSON result of
 * current weather data.
 * @baseWeatherUrl - initial OpenWeatherMap API access string
 * @weatherUrl - Full OpenWeatherMap API access string
 */

export default getWeather = () => {

    const theLocation = useLocation();
    const theCurrentUnit = useContext(CurrentUnitContext);

    const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

        const { WEATHER_API_KEY } = require("../clientSecret/openWeather.json");

        let baseWeatherUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?', 
            weatherUrl = "";
        //console.log(theLocation); //confirm we are getting location, uncomment if needed

        if (theLocation !== undefined) {

            weatherUrl = `${baseWeatherUrl}lat=${theLocation.latitude}&lon=${theLocation.longitude}&units=${theCurrentUnit}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
            console.log(weatherUrl); //uncomment if needed

            const fetchWeather = async () => {

                try {

                const response = await fetch(weatherUrl);
                const result = await response.json();

                    if (response.ok) {

                        setCurrentWeather(result);

                    } else {

                        alert(result.message);

                    };

                } catch (error) {

                    console.log(error);
                    alert(error.message);
                    
                } finally {
                    console.log("async function fetchWeather() has been run."); //API rate call confirmation
                };

            };

            //API calls must not occur more than once every minute.
            fetchWeather();

        };

    }, [theLocation, theCurrentUnit]);

    return currentWeather;

};
```

As shown right now, the error message that appears is:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating >'_CurrentUnitContext.CurrentUnitContext.Provider')
>
> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

Answer (score 1):

I was assisted, in CurrentUnitContext.js, changing

```
export default CurrentUnitContext = createContext();
```

to

```
export let CurrentUnitContext = createContext();
```

fixed the error.